# Can't retrieve anonymous authenticated user's info on first login

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire

**Logic**: users select a few items on the *homepage*, then click a 'confirm' button which starts a Firebase `$signInAnonymously()` auth flow. Their selection is stored under their `users/{uid}` branch in the database tree and they are redirected to a *checkout page* that retrieves their selection and asks for more information to proceed.

**Issue**: when the user lands on the checkout page for the first time their auth state cannot be retrieved (so their selection doesn't appear). However when they refresh the page, everything works as expected for all subsequent attempts (their user info is stored and now retrievable)

**Code**:

- User auth and selection setter/getter factory `userService`

  ```
  var auth = $firebaseAuth();
  var usersRef = $firebaseRef.users; // custom ref in app config

  // Authenticate anonymously to create user session
  function startSession() {
    return auth.$signInAnonymously()
      .then(function(user) {
        return user;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  // Check authentication state before everything loads
  function checkAuthState() {
    return $q(function(resolve) {
      var unsubscribe = auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          unsubscribe();
          resolve(user);
        }
        else {
          console.log('User unidentified');
        }
      });
    });
  }

  // Save user's menu selection into selection node of firebase
  function saveSelection(items, user) {
    var selectionRef = usersRef.child(user.uid).child('selection');
    for (var i = 0, item; !!(item = items[i]); i++) {
      var id = item.id;
      if (item.selected) {
        selectionRef.child(id).update(item);
      }
      else if (typeof(selectionRef.child(id)) !== 'undefined') {
        selectionRef.child(id).remove();
      }
    }
  }

  // Get user's selection from firebase
  function getSelection(user) {
    var selectionRef = usersRef.child(user.uid).child('selection');
    return $q(function(resolve) {
      var selection = $firebaseArray(selectionRef);
      resolve(selection);
    });
  }
  ```
- Menu controller:

  ```
    var menu = this;
    menu.saveMenu = saveMenu;

    // Save menu selection and create anonymous user on firebase
    function saveMenu() {
      var items = menu.items;
      return userService.startSession()
        .then(function(user) {
          return userService.saveSelection(items, user);
        });
    }
  ```
- Checkout controller:

  ```
  // Get selected menu items from user data
  function getCheckoutItems() {
    return userService.checkAuthState()
    .then(function(user) {
      return userService.getSelection(user);
    })
    .then(function(selection) {
      checkout.items = selection;
      return checkout.items;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
  ```

I've looked through dozens of posts on SO before asking this. Here are a couple of the similar ones I've found:
[Apparent race condition getting firebase.User from controller in Firebase 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054491/apparent-race-condition-getting-firebase-user-from-controller-in-firebase-3-x)
[Handle asynchronous authentication in Firebase on page reload to get list that needs user's uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534822/handle-asynchronous-authentication-in-firebase-on-page-reload-to-get-list-that-n)

I've also looked through the reference on GitHub to set it up:
https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#firebaseauth

NB: I'm using the new version of Firebase with Angular 1.5.8:

```
"firebase": "^3.4.1",
"angularfire": "^2.0.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Got it. I had to add a `resolve` to my `/checkout` route to wait for authentication before loading elements on the page... Figured it out thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692046/angularjs-routes-and-resolve-with-new-firebase-auth) by David East from the Firebase team.

```
resolve: {
      // controller will not be loaded until $waitForSignIn resolves
      "firebaseUser": function($firebaseAuthService) {
        return $firebaseAuthService.$waitForSignIn();
      }
    }
```